# Command: Swtich to Certain Window

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I currently have to use Gnome 3 [because of this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714540/login-doesnt-work-anymore-after-gnome-3-installed), so I don't have the handy shortcuts like `[super] + 2` opening the second application (Firefox) in my launcher available.

What I want to do, is a to create custom shortcuts for these. Which command do I have to execute to in order to started Firefox if it isn't running and switching to the window of Firefox if it already is running?

Firefox – of course – only is an example. But it's the program I care most about. Ideally, it should also work with Evolution and Nautilus / Nemo.

Comment: I replaced the first non-comment line with `MYPROG='firefox'` and it always opens a new window of Firefox, regardless of whether one is already open or not.

Comment: You are obviously not referring to my answer there, I cannot speak for Serg. If you'd like to use his answer, you could leave him a comment.